# VS code autocomplete just dashes and not options

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

While typing code in python, VS code autocomplete just shows dashes. When I click an option, they work but I don't know how it is going to complete. Here's a pic -
[Autocomplete not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNYJt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try reinstalling the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to the latest version, or install a pre-release version.

[image]

If the problem is still not resolved, please uninstall VS Code and [reinstall](https://code.visualstudio.com/) it.

Comment: I tried doing both, but nothing worked. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: If the issue is still not resolved, please try to file an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) on GitHub.